# Are we able to filter Partition Key when getting all entities from Azure Tables?

Tags: php, azure, azure-table-storage

As mentioned in the title, I was wondering whether it is possible to filter Partition Key when getting all entities from Azure Tables?

I tried adding it in filter, but it doesn't work:

```
$filter = "PartitionKey eq '" . $fields['authorId'] . "'";
$tableRest_result = $this->tableRestProxy->queryEntities($this->_tables['THEME']['SETTINGS'], $filters);
$entities = $tableRest_result->getEntities();
```

I am using PHP to access Azure tables.

Your help is most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `possible to filter Partition Key`? Do you want to fetch only the PartitionKeys from the table when you execute the query?

Comment: GauravMantri, yes! e.g. my partitionkeys are the user id from user table. I just want to retrieve the entities that has partitionkeys of the specified user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible to do so. Table service REST API supports **`query projection`** where you could fetch a subset of attributes from a table for each entity (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/09/15/windows-azure-tables-introducing-upsert-and-query-projection.aspx).

I briefly looked at the code on Github for PHP SDK (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Table/Models/QueryEntitiesOptions.php) and I think you should be able to specify the fields you want the query to return using `addSelectField()` method. If I'm not mistaken, this is part of `QueryEntitiesOption` which you can specify as a parameter to your `queryEntities` function (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Table/TableRestProxy.php). I don't work with PHP so I haven't tried it myself. Do give it a try and see if that works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above answer is right check [this unit test](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/tests/unit/WindowsAzure/Table/TableRestProxyTest.php#L549) to see how it works